# Unable to find a suitable version for angular - bower install

Tags: angularjs, heroku, bower

I have set up my Angular app so when it's pushed to Heroku it runs `bower install`. However I'm getting errors due to version issues.

When I run `bower install` locally I get presented with this:

```
Unable to find a suitable version for angular, please choose one:                                                                           
    1) angular#1.2.16 which resolved to 1.2.16 and is required by angular-resource#1.2.16                                                   
    2) angular#1.2.23 which resolved to 1.2.23 and is required by angular-cookies#1.2.23                                                    
    3) angular#>= 1.0.8 which resolved to 1.2.25 and is required by angular-ui-router#0.2.10                                                
    4) angular#^1 which resolved to 1.2.25 and is required by angular-ui-codemirror#0.1.6                                                   
    5) angular#~1.2.2 which resolved to 1.2.25 and is required by splitter#f5c2195050                                                       
    6) angular#>=1.0.6 which resolved to 1.2.25 and is required by angular-elastic#2.4.0                                                    
    7) angular#~1.2 which resolved to 1.2.25 and is required by angular-nanoscroller#0.2.1                                                  
    8) angular#~1.2.9 which resolved to 1.2.25 and is required by angular-sockjs#0.0.1Prefix the choice with ! to persist it to bower.json  

? Answer::
```

What should I do with this - I actually need version 1.3 of Angular because of the debounce feature

My `bower.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "json3": "~3.3.1",
    "es5-shim": "~3.1.0",
    "angular-resource": "1.2.16",
    "angular-sanitize": "1.2.16",
    "angular-animate": "1.2.16",
    "angular-ui-router": "~0.2.10",
    "jquery": "~2.1.1",
    "angular-ui-codemirror": "~0.1.6",
    "splitter": "*",
    "angular-cookies": "~1.2.23",
    "angular-elastic": "~2.4.0",
    "angular-local-storage": "~0.0.7",
    "chance": "~0.5.6",
    "nanoscroller": "~0.8.4",
    "angular-nanoscroller": "~0.2.1",
    "angular-sockjs": "~0.0.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Update your current angular dependencies to 1.3.x and add a resolution for angular to suppress the prompt:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.3.x",
    "angular-animate": "~1.3.x",
    "angular-cookies": "~1.3.x",
    "angular-resource": "~1.3.x",
    "angular-sanitize": "~1.3.x",
    "angular-ui-router": "~0.2.10",
    "angular-ui-codemirror": "~0.1.6",
    "angular-elastic": "~2.4.0",
    "angular-local-storage": "~0.0.7",
    "angular-nanoscroller": "~0.2.1",
    "angular-sockjs": ">=0.0.1",
    "json3": "~3.3.1",
    "es5-shim": "~3.1.0",
    "jquery": "~2.1.1",
    "splitter": "*",
    "chance": "~0.5.6",
    "nanoscroller": "~0.8.4"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": "~1.3.x"
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but can you tell me will there be any problem with angular-ui-router (#0.2.10) since it uses older angular? My doubt is can I every time go with the latest version blindly?

Comment: @AsimKT Did you manage to find a strategy to deal with these kind of issues? I mean it is quite frustrating at times because you find that you are using a module that depends on an older version of angular and there is another one added by another dev depending on the later version and they are both very important to your projects!! I wonder how other teams are dealing with this issue!!

Comment: No, I haven't. I think it's okay to go with new versions if it's not a major release change. I need a plugin for my project which have this issue. I used the latest dependency and it worked okay. Although I raised an issue in their repo to bump the version and they did. And you are right, we all face these issues!!

Answer (score 20):

A very good explanation and resolution of the issue can be found here:

[bower-resolutions](http://jaketrent.com/post/bower-resolutions/)

*Just copy pasting some lines here for reference:*

When you specify dependencies for you app via Bower, some of the packages might rely on different versions of the same library. You will have to resolve what version of libraries your app actually wants. In other words, you break the tie. But you don’t want to break it every time, so save your choice.

When you run bower install, the resolution process is interactive. When bower recognizes that there are two packages that depend on a package at different versions, it’ll list all those versions and ask:

[image]

The next line in the prompt is very handy. It reads:

[image]

Awesome! So, if I type !2 instead, my choice is saved in bower.json. Specifically, it’ll add a resolutions entry:

[image]

Now, the next time you run bower install, there is no interactive question of what version I want because I’ve already resolved that ember for my app should be version 1.5.1.

Answer (score 9):

You should update bower (It works for me):

```
bower update
```

Answer (score 5):

Delete your **/bower_components** directory and run `bower install` again..

A hack but works nevertheless..!!

Answer (score 1):

You can run the install command and when it prompts for selection of version then use (!) exclamation mark as prefix to option. For example !3 for third option.
This would then get added to bower.json file of your application and resolve the conflict.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

First try this:

**npm install -g bower**

If above solution does not work then, Try:

**bower update**
Worked for me.