# AngularJS application deployment to Heroku, unable to find suitable angular-animate version

Tags: angularjs, heroku, bower

I am deploying an AngularJS application to Heroku but am getting this error in the console:

```
remote: bower    ECONFLICT Unable to find suitable version for angular-animate
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to test-app-12345
```

The problem (of course) seems to be with the `angular-animate` dependency.

I am using a Heroku angularJS buildpack "[Yo Angular](https://github.com/nknj/heroku-buildpack-yo-angular)" and have followed their 4 step process for a successful application deployment to Heroku.

I tried fixing this by changing my `bower.json` file like recommended in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25916144/2669297), hoping it would solve my issue. It did not.

Locally, I use `grunt serve` to start the application and that works for me just fine.

My `bower.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "dashboard",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "main": "index.html",
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "~2.0",
    "bootstrap": "~3.1.1",
    "angular": "~1.3.15",
    "angular-ui-router": "~0.2",
    "angular-animate": "~1.3.15",
    "angular-resource": "~1.3.15",
    "angular-cookies": "~1.3.15",
    "angular-mocks": "~1.3.15",
    "angular-ui-utils": "~0.1",
    "angular-bootstrap": "~0.11.2",
    "moment": "~2.5",
    "less.js": "~1.6",
    "font-awesome": "~4.2.0",
    "form-builder": "0.1.0",
    "restangular": "~1.4.0",
    "lodash": "~2.4.1",
    "satellizer": "~0.3.2",
    "angular-xeditable": "~0.1.8",
    "fullcalendar": "~2.1.1",
    "angular-ui-calendar": "~0.8.1",
    "checklist-model": "~0.1.3"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "font-awesome": "~4.2.0",
    "jquery": "~2.0",
    "fullcalendar": "~2.1.1",
    "angular": "~1.3.15",
    "angular-bootstrap": "~0.11.2"
  }
}
```

The code is public for now, so here is the link to the [Github repo](https://github.com/djlovegrind/gunsDash).

Anyone have tips for me, or a good idea of what I am doing wrong?

P.S. I found [this information](https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/866) in `bower`'s Github issues tracking, which is dealing with the same problem. Might be helpful in figuring this out.

Comment: It seems it cannot find the suitable version for `angular-animate` because of the `x` in `~1.3.x`. Try to declare specific version like `~1.3.15`. I think it will throw an error for the other `.x` versions. Try to replace that also.

Comment: Did you update all the `.x` version or just the `angular-animate`?

Comment: Just angular animate, I thought since that was the only one giving me an error.... but I'll go back and try it with all.

Comment: Yeah, updated them all. Still did not work.

Comment: @AlbertoI.N.J. thanks anyways for your suggestion though! I appreciate the help.

Comment: It's strange. I already encountered that problem before and the reason was that the versions of the dependencies were conflicting to each other. Try to change the `angular-mocks` version same with the `angular` version.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82781/discussion-between-zach-cook-and-alberto-i-n-j).

Comment: Did you try running `bower` in your local? Is there any error?

Comment: Is the `bower` asking for any `version` related question?

Comment: Nope it doesn't do that.... I know what you are talking about, that has happened to me in the past, not with this app though.

Comment: Ok. I'm still investigating about your error. I'll get to you when I get the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error occurs when two packages reference different versions of the same dependency.

You can resolve the issue by running `rm -rf bower_components/ ; bower install`

Then when prompted to choose a version prefix your answer with a "!" like I have below. **Notice how bower will add a `"resolutions"` section.**

```
Unable to find a suitable version for angular-animate, please choose one:
    1) angular-animate#~1.2 which resolved to 1.2.28 and is required by form-builder#0.1.0
    2) angular-animate#~1.3.15 which resolved to 1.3.17 and is required by dashboard
    3) angular-animate#~1.4.3 which resolved to 1.4.3

Prefix the choice with ! to persist it to bower.json

? Answer: !3
```

## Here is your resolved `bower.json` file.

```
{
  "name": "dashboard",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "main": "index.html",
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "~2.0",
    "bootstrap": "~3.1.1",
    "angular": "~1.3.15",
    "angular-ui-router": "~0.2",
    "angular-animate": "~1.4.3",
    "angular-resource": "~1.3.15",
    "angular-cookies": "~1.3.15",
    "angular-mocks": "~1.3.15",
    "angular-ui-utils": "~0.1",
    "angular-bootstrap": "~0.11.2",
    "moment": "~2.5",
    "less.js": "~1.6",
    "font-awesome": "~4.2.0",
    "form-builder": "0.1.0",
    "restangular": "~1.4.0",
    "lodash": "~2.4.1",
    "satellizer": "~0.3.2",
    "angular-xeditable": "~0.1.8",
    "fullcalendar": "~2.1.1",
    "angular-ui-calendar": "~0.8.1",
    "checklist-model": "~0.1.3"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "font-awesome": "~4.2.0",
    "jquery": "~2.0",
    "fullcalendar": "~2.1.1",
    "angular": "~1.3.15",
    "angular-bootstrap": "~0.11.2",
    "angular-animate": "~1.4.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Haha all I actually had to do was `rm -rf bower_components/ ; bower install` -- then I was good to go!