# I got unable to choose suitable version when running bower install

Tags: angularjs, bower

When I am running bower install I got below output to let me select one of the version of angular:

```
Unable to find a suitable version for angular, please choose one:
1) angular#~1.2.9 which resolved to 1.2.29 and is required by at-table#1.0.7
2) angular#~1.3 which resolved to 1.3.20 and is required by angular-notify#2.5.0
3) angular#>=1.0.8 which resolved to 1.5.3 and is required by ngstorage#0.3.10
4) angular#^1.5.0 which resolved to 1.5.3 and is required by cooltoo
5) angular#^1.0.8 which resolved to 1.5.3 and is required by angular-ui-router#0.2.18
6) angular#1.5.3 which resolved to 1.5.3 and is required by angular-cookies#1.5.3
7) angular#^1.1.5 which resolved to 1.5.3 and is required by angular-file-upload#2.2.0
8) angular#^1.2 which resolved to 1.5.3 and is required by ng-table#0.8.3
```

But in my bower.json file, I have set the version of angular and I don't know why it complains about the version.

```
"dependencies": {
"requirejs": "~2.1.20",
"angular": "^1.5.0",
"angular-ui-router": "^0.2.18",
"bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
"jquery": "^2.2.1",
"angular-cookies": "^1.5.2",
"ngstorage": "^0.3.10",
"at-table": "^1.0.7",
"angular-file-upload": "^2.2.0",
"angular-notify": "^2.5.0"
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to find a suitable version for angular - bower install](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25915729/unable-to-find-a-suitable-version-for-angular-bower-install)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependencies require 3 different versions of angular and Bower does not know which one to use, all three *require* three *different* minor versions:

1. angular#~1.2.9 which resolved to **1.2.29** and is required by
   at-table#1.0.7 2)
2. angular#~1.3 which resolved to **1.3.20** and is
   required by angular-notify#2.5.0 3)
3. angular#>=1.0.8 which resolved
   to **1.5.3** and is required by ngstorage#0.3.10
4. *the rest of the dependencies require 1.5.3* - so there is no problem with them

As you can see, the first 2 dependencies require earlier minor versions of angular (`1.2.9` and `1.3.20`). I checked and you are using the latest versions of those two plugins. This means you have 3 options:

1. You can either remove `at-table` and `angular-notify` and find alternatives.
2. Ask the authors to update their dependencies.
3. Clone the repos on GitHub and change the dependencies yourself ([here](https://github.com/samu/angular-table/blob/master/bower.json#L28) and [here](https://github.com/cgross/angular-notify/blob/master/bower.json#L34)).