# Unable to find a suitable version for angular installing UI-GRID

Tags: angularjs, bower, karma-jasmine, angular-ui-grid, bower-install

I'm installing ui-grid via bower but I get the following error. What is it? What I have to do? What I have to answer in terminal?

```
Unable to find a suitable version for angular, please choose one:
1) angular#>=1 <1.3.0 which resolved to 1.2.29 and is required by angular-bootstrap#0.12.1
2) angular#1.3.20 which resolved to 1.3.20 and is required by angular-animate#1.3.20, angular-mocks#1.3.20, angular-resource#1.3.20
3) angular#~1.3.8 which resolved to 1.3.20 and is required by angular-dashboard-seed
4) angular#>=1.2.16 1.4.x which resolved to 1.4.10 and is required by angular-ui-grid#3.1.1
5) angular#^1.0.8 which resolved to 1.5.5 and is required by angular-ui-router#0.2.18
6) angular#* which resolved to 1.5.5 and is required by angular-toastr#1.0.2
Prefix the choice with ! to persist it to bower.json
```

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25915729/unable-to-find-a-suitable-version-for-angular-bower-install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not an error. This is to allow the user to select which version of angular to include in the project. Go with #4 it's recommended for your version of ui-grid.