# Angular Material Calendar incompatibility?

Tags: angularjs, web, angular-material

I'm trying to use this cool little angular module:
https://angular-material-calendar.bradb.net/

When doing bower install I get:

```
Unable to find a suitable version for angular-material, please choose one by typing one of the numbers below:
1) angular-material#~0.11 which resolved to 0.11.4 and is required by material-calendar#0.2.14
2) angular-material#^1.0.9 which resolved to 1.0.9 and is required by public
```

It looks like this thing was developed in beta, and I can't get it to work with 1.0.9. Does anyone know any workarounds? This module is exactly what I'm looking for.

Thanks!

Comment: You could have a look at the similar issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25915729/unable-to-find-a-suitable-version-for-angular-bower-install

Answer (score 0):

Use `--force-latest` or add component version to resoltions key in `bower.json`

**Note**
For more info you could check the issue [here](https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/866). I hope this helped.